# Rails unit tests: Define a general setup method that will run before every test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I want to clear my database before each test I'm running. Where should I put the script for achieving this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I cannot imagine why you might want to do this, maybe you can try this one: https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

In any case, the statements that can be called before every test should be put in a call to setup:

```
setup do
    # statements executed on start of every test
end
```

**UPDATE**: To explain a little bit more:

One thing you can do is inside your `test_helper.rb` file:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  ### Common setup for all tests ###
  setup do
      # write code to clean up your database here
  end

end
```

Then in your actual test files, in which you have test classes deriving from `ActiveSupport::TestCase` you only have to `require 'test_helper'`.

In that way, before every test that you ever run, the setup code will be executed.

Does this explain a little bit more what I have written in my first answer?

Comment: I need it before every test I got many test classes and I don't want to repeat myself in each test class, and not even call the base class to do this for me. I just wnat it to happen automatically

Comment: @ChenKinnrot that is why I told you about setup..do. This is its purpose. I have enhanced my answer trying to explain that a little bit further.

Comment: I understand, thanks for explaining but what if I need another class specific setup? and don't want the developer to call the base setup?

Comment: Then this differentiates your case. This is a new requirement that does not come out of your initial question. But anyway, In that case you have to define another subclass of ActiveSupport::TestCase, e.g. MyTestCase, and put your setup .. do block inside it. Then all your tests should derive from it and not from ActiveSupport::TestCase. The particular developer who would want to use another specific setup would have to derive its test case from ActiveSupport::TestCase (and not MyTestCase) and either define another setup .. do or define nothing.